# Best host on Windows for UI-less processes

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-services, com+

We're planning a system running on Windows/.Net 3.5 that has a number of "services" that need to run in the background. Some will be active all of the time, but some will only be called occassionally and can be stood-up on demand.

As far as I can see, my options are:

- Windows Services - always running(?)
- IIS hosted something - called on   demand
- COM+/ .Net Enterprise Sevices - most complex option, but most powerful?

Distributed transactions is not a requirement, these are mainly computation engines, rather than transaction processors.

Does anyone have any experience of working with all of these and what further pros & cons can be claimed for each technology?

**EDIT**

Is suppose there are multiple ways of hosting code in IIS, web services, WCF (as pointed out below), any others? Relative pros/cons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF feels like the right way to go. There are still many choices to make. WCF provides a number of communication mechanisms and hosting environments:
WCF combines the following technologies under one set of APIs-
ASMX;
WSE;
Remoting;
COM+;
MSMQ.
So for instance you can use persistent messages from MSMQ for occassionaly connected clients or standard XML encoding SOAP messages over an HTTP transport layer. You can also use new features in 3.5 like binary encoding of XML or JSON encoding over HTTP.

Hosting environments include:
Console applications 
Windows services 
WCF services inside IIS 7.0
and on Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008 you can use WAS (Windows Activation Services) to host WCF services.

Different hosting environments have pros and cons. I suggest you look at MSDN for more details (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).

Because WCF encompasses a lot of functionality it is more difficult to learn than any one of the technologies it replaces. I still think it pays for itself in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the software will do, and how (and if) users or systems need to interact with it. Depending on those things, there may be one more, often overlooked, option: set it up as a scheduled task. This is often a very good alternative to a windows service, if the software is of the kind that will act on certain time intervals (check for a change in a database, act on the changed data and send it somewhere, for instance).

If you will have other systems talking directly to your software, I would imagine that a WCF application hosted in IIS would be a rather straighforward way. We use both those approaches in my current assignment; WCF services for looking up and storing data, and scheduled tasks for data calculations that run on a regular basis.

The scheduled task has one upside compared to the others in one specific field; it uses system resources only when running.

Comment: Scheduled tasks probably don't really apply in our case as the processing will be done on demand rather than at a specific time each day, but thanks for raising them here.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned starting up a process "on demand".  WAS - Windows Activation Service, or sometimes called Windows Process Activation Servvice, though it is never abbreviated "WPAS" - is the thing inside Windows that provides on-demand process activation.  The way it works - when a message arrives, WAS can start a worker process to handle the message.  WAS was, prior to IIS7, fairly tightly integrated into IIS. It was used primarily to activate processes that did web work - like an ASP.NET worker process.  With IIS7, WAS is generalized so that it can activate worker processes based on non-HTTP as well as HTTP messages. If you write your app to receive messages through WCF, you can get activation essentially "for free".  That applies if it is HTTP, TCP, MSMQ; SOAP or otherwise.

The key thing with this on-demand startup though, is that it is tied to the communication. In fact the process lifecycle model for WAS is tied to communication as well. By default if there are no incoming messages after a while, the process will be shut down by WAS.  That may or may not be what you want.

As for process hosting - COM+ offers a hosting environment but it is primarily intended for use as a host for processes that communicate.  This may not be the perfect fit for you.

If you have compute engines, you may just want to run a Windows Service.  A service like that can be started and stopped either administratively or programmatically.  In the latter case, you could imagine a WAS-activated worker process programmatically starting a windows service.

You could also imagine writing a simple Windows Service that watches a location (filesystem, message queue, etc) for a message, and when that file or message arrives, the Windows Service starts up a compute engine process, which itself is NOT a Windows Service, but is just a process.

Speaking of MSMQ - That is basically the same model as MSMQ triggers.  You can configure MSMQ to start a process when a message arrives on a particular queue.

There are lots of options.